# jQuery Check for tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a media query to load in a stylesheet (if device is a tablet).

I was just wondering how I could check in my javascript if the user is using a tablet, is there a check or should I just check what stylesheet was loaded in?

Comment: The media query is most likely detecting tablet based on screen size. You could do the same thing with JS by detecting the Window size.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. A tablet is a mobile device, but a mobile device is not always a tablet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to see if perhaps this sheds a light on your question:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)

As the answer to that thread says, I'd suggest to rely on 'feature detection' rather than tablet vs non-tablet (as it may not be as straightforward as one may think) hence --> http://modernizr.com/

Comment: I agree with using feature detection whenever possible, but there are some scenarios when using userAgents may work better. What if I wanted to have crazy canvas image filters that bogged down the processor to not run on tablets/mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the useragent from the server into the page so that JavaScript knows exactly what browser is being reported.

Answer (score 1):

You can use navigator.userAgent and do a substring search to find out which tablet viewing your site.  Here is a current list of tablet userAgent 
http://mojosunite.com/tablet-user-agent-strings

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Chris. This gave me exactly what I was looking for with dealing with user agent!